# Select query takes too much time to retrieve datafor blank values in EventName column of Tracker response Table

Tags: sql-server

TrackerResponse table with columns and indexes:

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the query you're performing against the database?

Comment: (SELECT TOP 10 TrackerResponse.EventName,TrackerResponse.ReceiveTime,ISNull(TrackerResponse.InputStatus,0) AS InputStatus,
TrackerResponse.Latitude,TrackerResponse.Longitude,TrackerResponse.Speed,
TrackerResponse.TrackerID,TrackerResponse.OdoMeter,TrackerResponse.Direction,
                    UserCar.CarNo FROM TrackerResponse
                    INNER JOIN UserCar ON (UserCar.TrackerID = TrackerResponse.TrackerID)
                    WHERE  (TrackerResponse.EventName IS NOT NULL AND TrackerResponse.EventName<>'')
                    AND TrackerResponse.TrackerID = 112 Order By ID DESC)

Comment: TrackerID 112 takes too much time while 118 is ok

Answer (score 0):

Try re-organzing or re-building your IX_TrackerResponse_EventName index if it is very fragmented.

The query speed is affected by what columns you are including in the SELECT query.

Try testing the speed of these different queries, and view the Execution Plans in Query Analyzer.

```
-- this query will only need to use the EventName index
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TrackerResponse
WHERE EventName = ''

-- this query will use the index if there are relatively few blank values, 
-- but if there are large number of blank values, the engine may do a full scan of the clustered table index
SELECT * FROM TrackerResponse
WHERE EventName = ''


-- see how many non-blank records you have
select TrackerID, count(*)
from TrackerResponse
where EventName IS NOT NULL AND EventName<>''
group by TrackerID
order by TrackerID

-- see how many blank records you have
select TrackerID, count(*)
from TrackerResponse
where EventName IS NULL OR EventName=''
group by TrackerID
order by TrackerID
```

Is there a big difference in the amounts for your different TrackerID values?

Comment: (SELECT TOP 10 TrackerResponse.EventName,TrackerResponse.ReceiveTime,ISNull(TrackerResponse.InputStatus,0) AS InputStatus,
TrackerResponse.Latitude,TrackerResponse.Longitude,TrackerResponse.Speed,
TrackerResponse.TrackerID,TrackerResponse.OdoMeter,TrackerResponse.Direction,
                    UserCar.CarNo FROM TrackerResponse
                    INNER JOIN UserCar ON (UserCar.TrackerID = TrackerResponse.TrackerID)
                    WHERE  (TrackerResponse.EventName IS NOT NULL AND TrackerResponse.EventName<>'')
                    AND TrackerResponse.TrackerID = 118 Order By ID DESC)

Comment: TrackerID 112 takes too much time while 118 is ok